# Facebook UID from response doesn't match with user's uid stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, uid

I have a problem on production with Facebook login which happened today. 
I'm using Rails omniouth-facebook gem for authentication users via Fb.

So, after some debugging I figure out that `uid` which I got in response from Facebook isn't the same as `uid` which particular user has stored in database.

I have this part:

```
find_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
```

where auth is `env['omniauth.auth']` and when I manually check user with auth.email in my database **`uids` not matched**, so this function always returns nil and Login Failure.

Does anybody has idea what could be the problem? Really would appreciate any hint.

Thanks,
Bojan

Comment: Is the UID scoped? Depending on API and context Facebook may return ids unique to a relationship with a particular page.

Comment: I don't know is it scoped, I suppose yes as I have Fb application registered. And also on staging pretty much the same configuration and everything works fine

Comment: I just checked, it is scoped as it use V2.5

The point is that it was working about 4-5 hours ago, and I'm not sure what's happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With API v2.0, Facebook introduced app-scoped user ids.

For every new user that logs in to your app after the switch was made to 2.0, you will not get their “global” user id any more, but only an app-scoped one, that is unique to your app - to be more specific, it is tied to your app id.

So if you are using different app ids, resp. switched app ids at some point, of course you will get different app-scoped ids for the same user.

If you have a business that has several apps, you can connect them via Business Manager, so that you can connect the different app-scoped user ids for different apps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

So the point here is that this is only one application which we are using for production and we are using it sincy January this year. 
Everything was perfect since yesterday, when I noticed this issue. We didn't touch App neither Facebook_key/Facebook_secret there.
So right now our existing users complain as they can't login via Facebook and we have to find solution quickly. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: App-scoped user ids are supposed to stay the same, for the same app id. If that is not the case, file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Also what I noticed, when I try to do something like:
www.facebook.com/user_id it works with both uids. Mine from database for existing user and new one from response. 

Maybe I should update them all with new one ?

Comment: When I use this 
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token

I'm getting different uid that I have in database.

Also using this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ with token I'm getting from the response I see that there is a diff UID then I have in database.

I just don't know how that's happened as App credentials are the same and nothing was changed.

Comment: The first thing is normal - `www.facebook.com/{app-scoped-user-id}` is supposed to redirect to the “real” profile URL in a browser. / Again, if you are _sure_ that the app id used is still the same - file a bug report; that should not happen.